Should an API client class be reusable?
For an API client I am working on, I was wondering, whether the main class should be reusable. This question basically boils down to: should the HTTP client be instantiated in __init__ or __enter__/_request.
Usage at the moment:
client = ApiClient()
with client:
    client.get_user()
    # Additional requests to use connection pooling.

# Can reopen the connection, as the HTTP client is instantiated in __enter__
with client:
    client.get_user()

But maybe, the client instance shouldn't be reusable, as it doesn't provide any advantage other than storing the ApiKey, and the non-usable type is the expected behavior from an HTTP client:
# Main usage then, reopening wouldn't work.
with ApiClient() as client:
    client.get_user()

Below you'll find the full code for the reusable variant for reference (with most of the endpoints missing obviously):
class ApiClient:
    def __init__(self, api_key: str = os.environ["API_KEY"]) -> None:
        """Instantiate a new API client."""

        self.api_key = api_key

    def __enter__(self):
        self.connect()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exception_type, exception_value, exception_traceback):
        self.close()
        del self.client

    def _request(self, method: str, endpoint: str, data: dict | None = None):
        if not hasattr(self, "client"):
            self.connect()
        request = self.client.build_request(method=method, url=endpoint, data=data)
        response = self.client.send(request)
        response.raise_for_status()
        return response.json()

    def get_user(self):
        return self._request("GET", "/api/me")

    def connect(self):
        headers = {"Api-Key": self.api_key}
        base_url = "https://login.smoobu.com"
        self.client = httpx.Client(base_url=base_url, headers=headers)

    def close(self):
        self.client.close()


The design you have at the moment is not thread safe. Also using an object after context manager quits is an anti pattern in general.

Could you elaborate in the thread safety? And thank you for the comment about the context manager quit, that helps!

Well, consider what happens when you do client = ApiClient() and then two threads do with client: .... In particular when __exit__ is called twice on the same ApiClient.

If I was a user of your class, it would have never occurred to me to reuse a context manager object. Most context managers do not support this. That is, they tend to pass through the states "init → enter → exit → delete" without being able to cycle back. The httpx.Client is a perfect example since it cannot be re-opened. Personally, I think your client should ask for a httpx.Client as a dependency, not own it. That way, the caller can control the client's lifecycle.

@amon It depends on what context is being managed. sqlite3 and psycopg2, for example, let you create a single connection object that, when used as a context manager, starts and commits a new transaction, rather than auto-closing a connection.

It all depends on the work the needs to be done during the initialization.
When you do:
with ApiClient() as client:
    ...

I suppose that there are a series of operations that need to be done before you start doing the actual queries. It may be, for instance, that you need to retrieve the URI of the API from the settings, or initialize the user, or—who knows?—make a check to the API to see if it is responding (and if not, handle it on client side in a very specific way).
All those tasks may take CPU cycles that you are not ready to spend on every request. In this case, keeping an instance of the ApiClient class may make sense.
Another reason to have one instance is dependency injection. If at some point you need to inject the API client, rather than initializing it every time (for instance in order to render the consumer class—the class that relies on the API client—testable, making it possible to replace ApiClient by a mock), then having one instance injected in the constructor is a common solution (although nothing prevents you from injecting a function that would create an instance).
Finally, a third reason to use a long-lived instance would be to keep the resources active. For instance, ApiClient may want to reuse the same HTTP connection for multiple requests, instead of creating a connection every time (which also means performing TLS handshake for every with block).

CPU cycles are negligible in networking. Dependency injection would not inject an object closeable by client. Depending on TLS version, handshake may take multiple roundtrips, so that's the real reason.

I'm going to side-step the issue of whether this is worth doing and just focus on a simple coding solution which cleans things up:
class ApiClientPool:
    def __init__(self, api_key: str = os.environ["API_KEY"]) -> None:
        """Instantiate a new API client pool."""
        self.api_key = api_key

    def client():
        return ApiClient(self.api_key)

class ApiClient:
    def __init__(self, api_key) -> None:
        """Instantiate a new API client."""
        self.api_key = api_key

    def __enter__(self):
        headers = {"Api-Key": self.api_key}
        base_url = "https://login.smoobu.com"
        self.client = httpx.Client(base_url=base_url, headers=headers)

    def __exit__(self, exception_type, exception_value, exception_traceback):
        self.client.close()

    def _request(self, method: str, endpoint: str, data: dict | None = None):
        request = self.client.build_request(method=method, url=endpoint, data=data)
        response = self.client.send(request)
        response.raise_for_status()
        return response.json()

    def get_user(self):
        return self._request("GET", "/api/me")

ApiClientPool is just the first name that came to mind so don't get hung up on it.  The use of this becomes:
with pool.client() as client:
   client.get_user()

The main advantage here is that you can pass/inject a pool instance instead of the API_KEY.
Depending on the context this is used in, I think a module-level solution instead of the additional class would be fine in a lot of cases.  Of course, that would only make sense if there's a single API key per application instance.  If you have more than one thing that you need to share across client instances, this kind of thing becomes more obviously useful.  It also positions you to actually pool connections if that is desirable.
